# Reassembling Serial data sent from Arduino to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

I am trying to send six integers at a time through Serial.write() on arduino and send them to python. so far, I have managed to turn the Integers into byte pointers (I think thats the name) and send them over serial. however, when I try to reassemble them on the python side, I get some strange numbers that I did not intend to see.

Arduino Code:

```
int myInts[6]= {1455, 1446, 6766, 974, 365, 455};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{  

  byte *p = (byte)myInts;
  for(byte i = 0; i < sizeof(myInts); i++){
    Serial.write(p[i]);
  }
}
```

Python Code

```
import argparse
import numpy
import time
import serial 
import struct

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
    b = ser.read(4)

    i = struct.unpack('i' ,b)
    print(i)
```

Output:

(-1090650113,)
(285341695,)
(10683141,)
(-1090650177,)
(285341695,)
(10683141,)

Thanks!

Vik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will offer several alternatives.  **Easiest one is listed last.**

First thing you should realize is that `int` is a different size on the two platforms.  Arduino `int` is a signed 16-bit int, -32768 -> 32767.  Your python `int` is a 32-bit int.  Certainly the numbers being returned are far outside the range of any 16-bit number.

I would recommend changing your `int` in the Arduino to `unsigned int` and then change your python unpack format string to `H` (unsigned short).  Or, leave the Arduino as `int` and change your python unpack format string to 'h' (short) and see if that makes a difference for you.  Oh and of course you should change to `b = ser.read(2)` because these are now all 2-byte integers.

Next, Arduino's `Serial.write()` method supports a single byte, a string, or a buffer with a length.  Not a byte pointer.  So while I don't have an Arduino here in front of me to test, I think you should be using the `Serial.write(buf,len)` form of the command and get rid of the "byte pointers", which I've never seen mentioned in any Arduino documentation:

```
Serial.write(myInts, 12);
```

**Finally, the easiest thing to do is simply to use `Serial.print(str)` or Serial.println(str) and send a string across.  Then on the python side simply convert the string to an integer type of your choosing.**

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a perfect reply! In the past, I was using the Serial.println() from arduino, but I was getting some weird strings on the python side, such as "/xff" or "/xfe". I also read that Serial.write() is better for sending data, which is why I wanted to use bytes, since I feared that using Strings would cause the problem, like it did with Serial.print() . What do you think?

Comment: @VikramB I think strings are easiest on Arduino.  I'm glade to have helped, and hope you'll click the check mark to "Accept" my answer if I feel my answer is best.

Comment: I have tried sending a string through the Serial.write by casting the integer I want to send to a string, but I get:"no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::write(String&)'     "

Comment: @VikramB Indeed.  I misread the documentation:  "write()

Description

Writes binary data to the serial port. This data is sent as a byte or series of bytes; to send the characters representing the digits of a number use the print() function instead.  So use print() or println().  Sorry for the confusion.